# Stringstream is allowing getline call in function

Tags: c++, cin, stringstream

I am passing by reference a stringstream that I assembled from cin to a class function. When I call `streamstream.str()` in the class function, all of the input is there. However, on the next line, when I call `getline(stringstream,output)`, it fails and never starts the loop. What is wrong with my stringstream?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

class HRMLMap{
    public:
        HRMLMap(stringstream& iss){
            string line;
            cout << iss.str() << endl;
            while(getline(iss,line)){
                cout << "it never gets here." << "\n";
            }
        }

};




int main() {
    std::string line;
    stringstream ss("", ios_base::app | ios_base::out);
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i){
        getline(cin,line);
        ss << line << endl;
    }
    HRMLMap myHRMLMap(ss);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: how do you know it does not start the loop? What is your 'fail' indication?

Comment: please show code that demonstrates the problem. See also [mcve]. Seems like you simplified it too much so that strictly speaking it does not show the behaviour you describe

Comment: declare ss as `stringstream ss;` you have not selected `in` - default should work good enough

Comment: NathanOliver, that code doesn't work. I tested it. I think you're conflating the output from iss.str() with the output from getline(). It never reaches inside the while loop.

Comment: @Ben Oops.  I forgot you added newlines.

Comment: Er, no, you've opened your stringstream for output with append every time. At what point should input work? Get rid of the `ios_base::app|ios_base::output`.

Comment: @Marek R, those edits completely change my question. I am undo-ing them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is with the mode you opened the `stringstream` with.  You used

```
stringstream ss("", ios_base::app | ios_base::out);
```

Which means you will appened to the stream and the stream is in output mode.  That means you can only write to it, which means you can't then read from it.

To fix it you can specify it also operates in input mode with

```
stringstream ss("", ios_base::app | ios_base::out | ios_base::in);
```

or you could just use

```
stringstream ss;
```

which gives you the same behavior.